# ObjectOutputStream read multiple Objects in a row

Tags: java, android, sockets, serialization, objectoutputstream

My problem is pretty simple at the first glance though it's not. My android app sends objects via ObjectOutputStream (OOS) using method writeObject().
Everything was just fine till I tried to send several objects in a short period of time (looks like that matters). So, immagine I do smth like:

Server side:

```
public void someMethod(){
    sendObjectA(objA);
    sendObjectB(objB);
}

public void sendObjectA(ObjectA obj){
    getObjectOutputStream().writeObject(obj);
    getObjectOutputStream().flush();
}

public void sendObjectB(ObjectB obj){
    getObjectOutputStream().writeObject(obj);
    getObjectOutputStream().flush();
}
```

Client side

```
public void method read(){
     while (true){
       Object receivedObject = inputStream.readObject();
       if (receivedObject instanceof ObjectA){
               doAThings();
       } else if (receivedObject instanceof ObjectB){
               doBThings();
       }
}
```

... catch exceptions etc.

And it happens somehow that doAThings() method never gets called, it looks more like that this objectA never comes.

While debugging I noticed that right after I've written objA to the stream, programm starts writings objB to it (well, quite obvious behaviour, but...) but client does not receive objA (I also tried to debug the client side). I put a breakpoint at the line

```
Object receivedObject = inputStream.readObject();
```

And it only stopped when it received objB.

No exceptions were thrown, no errors in logcat (like nonSerializable etc), nothing.

Also I would like to add that I won't be that satisfied receiving some kind of workaround. I really want to understand the root of the problem. I've read tons of different tutorials, documentations regarding java IO, streams etc, but still have no clue why such thing could happen. For instance, the flush() method supposed to flush any data written i.e. DELIVER it to a destination point, though in my case it does not. It looks like it just overwrite previously written data with a new one.

P.S. I'm also using sockets, so the receiver - is a device connected by Wi-Fi

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a `BufferedOutputStream` between your `ObjectOutputStream` and the socket. While this is a good idea, it means:

- you need to flush() the `ObjectOutputStream`directly after you construct it, and before trying to construct the corresponding `ObjectInputStream`
- if you want the peer to read objects as you produce them with no lag, you need to flush the `ObjectOutputStream` after every `writeObject()` call.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Well, I do flush objectoutputstream right after I've written them to the stream. But what do you mean by "you need to flush() the ObjectOutputStreamdirectly after you construct it"? Could you please explain what's the meaning of this and how  will it look like?